# Save PDF from Client to Server using JavaScript/AJAX

Tags: javascript, ajax, pdf

The *editable PDF (with forms)* is loaded in the browser at the *client* computer; is there a way save the PDF with the form data (in the PDF itself) and send the updated PDF back to the server via AJAX?

Because people don't read here are some basic clarifications:

- No frameworks / libraries.
- The PDF was loaded from the server.
- There is no "creation of PDF at the server".
- The PDF has a form with information that *must* be saved and sent along with the PDF *back to the server*.

Comment: Answer is in adobe acrobat docs pertaining to publishing pdf web forms

Comment: @charlietfl Is the form on the PDF compatible with submitting data to the server whether or not the PDF is embedded in the browser or displayed in a PDF viewer?

Comment: Should be so long as you edit it with proper config as outlined in acrobat docs. Personally i would convert to html form and build the pdf server side with data submitted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The justification for detailed pursuit no longer exists so I can only justify posting a link as an answer at this time.

https://helpx.adobe.com/acrobat/using/publishing-interactive-pdf-web-forms.html